# Pandas MultiIndex multi-dimentional intersection

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 2 Pandas Series objects that are both a subset of a common Multi-Indexed DF.
Example:

```
// SeriesA = 
Session    Movie #  Point in Time
Session A  mov1     1932             0.300000
                    1934             0.133333
                    1936             0.166667
                    1938             0.316667

// SeriesB = 
Session    Movie #  Point in Time
Session A  mov1     1932             0.300000
                    1934             0.133333
                    1940             0.200000
                    1942             0.083333
                    1944             0.133333
Session B  mov1     1932             0.500000
```

I'm trying to extract rows where all three index-levels exist in both SeriesA and SeriesB.
So for the example data above the correct result would be

```
expected = [('Session A', 'mov1', 1932), ('Session A', 'mov1', 1934)]
```

I tried using numy's intersect1d() and pandas' intersection() functions but both return a list of tuples where each tuple is all existing options for one of the index-labels, i.e.

```
result = [('Session A', Session B'), ('mov1'), (1932, 1934, 1936, 1938, 1940, 1942, 1944)]
```

I could iterate row-by-row but it seems VERY wasteful. Any magical solutions I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got correct output with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
a = SeriesA.index.intersection(SeriesB.index).tolist()
print (a)
[('Session A', 'mov1', 1932), ('Session A', 'mov1', 1934)]
```

Another idea with `merge`:

```
c = ['Session','Movie #','Point in Time']
a = (SeriesA.reset_index()
            .merge(SeriesB.reset_index(), on=c)
            .set_index(c)
            .index
            .tolist())
print (a)
[('Session A', 'mov1', 1932), ('Session A', 'mov1', 1934)]
```

Comment: thanks! casting it to a numpy array gave me what I needed